# How to delete div and all element inside div? Javascript, html, css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that clears the entire div and it disappears but still appears in the inspect (html). This is a real problem because we have this input type field on the email and I got this empty data in email. I only want when this value is not chosen to completely remove me from html and inspect.  Look at my code and try to catch the error.  The most important things in the whole code that you need to pay attention are `onchange="checkSelected()"` in html and first script tag which manipulate with that. It should simply become a display none but it still stands there.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="montageModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content" style="display: flex;">



         <div class="modal-body">


            <form id="schedule_form" class="clearfix" action="index.php?route=api/reifenmontage" method="post">

               <div class="container-fluid">

                  <div class="step_1"  >
                     <h3 class="modal-title">Reifenmontage Termin buchen  </h3>
                     <div class="row termin_row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                           <div class="row">
                              <label>Pneu-Typ</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                           <div class="row">
                              <select onchange="checkSelected()" class="form-control" name="pneu" id="pneu">
                                 <option value="Motorrad">Motorrad</option>
                                 <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
                              </select>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div id="additionalRow"  class="row termin_row" >
                     <div id="reifenmontage-input" class="row termin_row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                           <div class="row">
                              <label>Mark und model</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                           <div class="row">
                              <select name="marka" class="form-control" id="button-getdata">
                              </select>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                           <div class="row">
                              <select name="model" class="form-control" id="result" > 
                              </select> 
                           </div>
                        </div>

                     </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="row termin_row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                           <div class="row"><label>2. Terminvorschlag</label></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                           <div class="row">
                              <div class="input-group date" id="date-2" data-termin="1">
                                 <input type='text' class="form-control" name="date[1]" />
                                 <span class="input-group-addon">um</span>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                           <div class="row">
                              <div class="input-group time" id="time-2" data-termin="1">
                                 <input type='text' class="form-control" name="time[1]" />
                                 <span class="input-group-addon">Uhr</span>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                           <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" name="accept" id="accept"> Ich akzeptiere die <a href="teilnahmebedingungen" target="_blank">Teilnahmebedingungen</a>
                           </label>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                     <div class="row text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-submit" id="next_step" disabled="disabled">Anfrage senden</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="step_2">
                     <h3 class="modal-title">Your contact info</h3>

                     <div class="">
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                           <input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $user['name'] ?>" placeholder="Name and Lastname" class="form-control name text" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                           <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?= $user['phone'] ?>" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control phone text" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group clearfix">
                           <input type="email" name="email" value="<?= $user['email'] ?>" placeholder="Email" class="form-control email text" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                           <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-submit" >Suchen</button>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                  </div>

               </div>

            </form>

         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">SCHLIESSEN</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and my script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   let selectItem = document.getElementById('pneu');
   let additionalRow = document.getElementById('additionalRow');
   function checkSelected() {
      if (selectItem.selectedIndex == "1") {
         additionalRow.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
         additionalRow.style.display = 'block';
      }
   }
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-getdata').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=api/reifenmontage/get_marka_data',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#reifenmontage-input select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        success: function(json) {

            if (json['success']) {
               $("#result").empty();
                for (i in json['success']) {
                var element = json['success'][i];
                var o = new Option(element['model'], element['model']);
               $("#result").append(o);
                    html = "\t<option   value=\""+ element['model'] + "\">" + element['model'] + "</option>\n";
                    $("#result").append(o); 
                }
               //  document.getElementById("schedule_form").reset();
            }   

        }
    });
});
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajax({
 url: 'index.php?route=api/reifenmontage/mark',
 context: document.body,
 success: function(data) {
   const selectControl = $('#button-getdata');
   selectControl.html(data.map(ExtractData).join(''));
 }
});

function ExtractData(item) {
return ` <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>`;
}

</script>
```

Comment: where is the code which delete the div?

Comment: This is that code. I don't delete code I just display none that code. 
<script type="text/javascript">
   let selectItem = document.getElementById('pneu');
   let additionalRow = document.getElementById('additionalRow');
   function checkSelected() {
      if (selectItem.selectedIndex == "1") {
         additionalRow.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
         additionalRow.style.display = 'block';
      }
   }
</script>

I only want to hide from html and inspect when is not selected

Comment: Okey in Vue.js i Have direction v-show. If is v-show code is not display in html(inspect). It I want in jquery ...

Comment: So am I understanding this right, the element disappears from the rendered page as expected, because display was set to none successfully, but you expect it to disappear from the DOM inspector view as well? Then you would have to remove the element from the DOM, instead of just make it not display. (And if you are not even talking about the DOM inspector, but actually “source code view” in the browser - you can’t remove anything from there, that is just the initial HTML code the browser received. JS can not manipulate that at all.)

Comment: If you can reformat your question in a more readable way I may be able to assist you. I cannot understand what you have, what you want to do and whats wrong

Comment: 04FS but element not disappears from the rendered page.... He is again here. I try to explain you in photos.

Comment: Okey This is first photo. Row is selected and this is okey 
https://imgur.com/a/ekchqIn

Second photo I wan't this additional row in inspect....I want to not show...
https://imgur.com/a/usoF3bB

Comment: If you want to remove an HTMLElement from the DOM, just call `remove()` on it.

Comment: This is all work good when i set 

   let selectItem = document.getElementById('pneu');
   let additionalRow = document.getElementById('additionalRow');
   function checkSelected() {
      if (selectItem.selectedIndex == "1") { 
         additionalRow.remove();
      } else {
         additionalRow.style.display = 'block';
      }
   }

But I now can't to switch again on my first option 'Motorrad'
ahh.......
I switch to Motorrad but element is deleted from dom :/

Answer (score 1):

Try variant with detaching/attaching DOM elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   let selectItem = document.getElementById('pneu');
   //let additionalRow = document.getElementById('additionalRow');
   let detached = '';
   function checkSelected() {
      if (selectItem.selectedIndex == "1") {
         detached = $('#reifenmontage-input').detach();
      } else {
         detached.appendTo('#additionalRow');
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: But now my model and mark when is selected don't return value on email... ah :(

Comment: Can you show actual text of html snippet - child elements of the ```<div id="additionalRow">...</div>``` ?